# I want to have numbers between 0.00 - 20.00 with math.random but cannot seem to make it work

Tags: javascript

So here's my question. I'm trying to get random numbers between zero and twenty while including both 0.00 and 20.00. I cannot seem to figure out what I have to do make it work. This is my code so far.

Here's the line relevant to my question:

```
arrTemperaturer.push((Math.random() * (20)).toFixed(2));
```

Here's the code in context:

```
    arrTemperaturer=[];        
    function randomTemp(antDager){

     i=antDager;

         while(i>0){
             arrTemperaturer.push((Math.random() * (20)).toFixed(2));
             i--;
          }
    }
```

Comment: Codes in image screenshots is not allowed here. Please paste the code snippet in the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript there is no difference between the numbers `10` and `10.00`. That distinction can only be made with strings. This is why `toFixed()` returns a string. In general you should try to work with numbers until you need to display them, then convert to the appropriate string representation of the number with something like `toFixed()`.

If you want to make numbers between 0 and 20(inclusive) that are precise to two decimals, you can look for random numbers between 0 and 2001, take the `Math.floor()` which will give an integer, then divide by 100.

```js
let arr = Array.from({length:10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (2001))/100)
console.log(arr)
```

Just understand that until you convert to a string, numbers like `2.70` won't exist — it will be `2.7`. In practice, there's not much reason to do this; you can just use the full floats and convert at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm really new to javascript so still figuering out the basics. This was well written and easy to understand :)